# How to get height and width of the video in Angular 2, TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, video

I need to check if the video is portrait or landscape, for that I am trying to get the height, width of the video this way,

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-videplayer',
  template: `<video id="singleVideo">
                <source src="/assets/videoname.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>`
})
export class VideplayerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const videoElem: HTMLVideoElement = <HTMLVideoElement>document.getElementById('singleVideo');
    const vidH = videoElem.videoHeight;
    const vidW = videoElem.videoWidth;
    console.log(vidH, vidW); // this returns: 0, 0
  }

}
```

I tried getting the height, width of the video within constructor, ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit functions but I'm a getting 0 height and with all the time.

Comment: From MDN: _“If the element's ready state is HAVE_NOTHING, the value is 0”_ I think your best option here is to set up a `readystatechange` event handler, and then inside that check if the state is > 0, and then read the dimensions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState

Comment: did you try try videoElem = getSize() and see in console.

Comment: @CBroe: Your reference worked. Added obj.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() { }); and measured the dimensions within the callback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MDN, on the videoHeight/-Width properties:

> If the element's ready state is HAVE_NOTHING, the value is 0

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement

I think your best option here is to set up a `readystatechange` event handler, and then inside that check if the state is > 0 (HAVE_NOTHING), and then read the dimensions. (Next readyState would be 1/HAVE_METADATA, and from there on the video dimensions should be available.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState

Answer (score 2):

Try with `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` as below:

```
const vidH = videoElem.offsetHeight;    
const vidW = videoElem.offsetWidth;
```

And, if it still does not work then try with some `timeout` in `ngAfterViewInit()` as below:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(function () {
       const videoElem: HTMLVideoElement = <HTMLVideoElement>document.getElementById('singleVideo');
       const vidH = videoElem.offsetHeight;
       const vidW = videoElem.offsetWidth;
       console.log(vidH, vidW); // this returns: 0, 0
    }, 500);
}
```